# Sum unequal columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

Say I want to find the mean of each column in a dataframe but the number of data points in each column is different. If I convert the NaN to '' using `df.fillna('')` and use the `.sum()` method for a column,  I get " **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'**. " How can this be avoided?  I tried substituting 0.000001 for NaN but that didn't work either.

Comment: [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) has a `skipna` parameter which makes it skip all `NaN` values (and is on by default). So just `df.mean(axis=1)` should give you your desired result.

Comment: @Nick Excellent suggestion. Thanks.